# What do the * characters mean in this X window font description?

Tags: fonts, x11

In font ***-Adobe-Helvetica-Bold-R-Normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-*-**** what is the significance of `*` in each place?

For example: In above description 120 is font height.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `*` is a wildcard, meaning “use whatever you find for this, X font system”. I hardly ever use XLFDs (X Logical Font Descriptors) any more…

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thanks for more insight. I found this in old tcl code for displaying some text on buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xfontsel command can give you full description:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find succinct descriptions in the [XLFD Arch Linux article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_Logical_Font_Description). For full details, see the [XLFD Conventions, by the X Consortium Standard](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/XLFD/xlfd.html#fontname_field_definitions). Quoting from it, each field is, in order,

- FOUNDRY field
- FAMILY_NAME field
- WEIGHT_NAME field
- SLANT field
- SETWIDTH_NAME field
- ADD_STYLE_NAME field
- PIXEL_SIZE field
- POINT_SIZE field
- RESOLUTION_X and RESOLUTION_Y fields
- SPACING field
- AVERAGE_WIDTH field
- CHARSET_REGISTRY and CHARSET_ENCODING fields

and an asterisk is an wildcard, meaning that any available element may apply.